# Invoking javascript function from java with arguments

Tags: java, nashorn

I am struggling to invoke javascript function from java. My problem comes from the fact that whole function is actually received as a string argument:

```
public void selectMethod(Map<T> item, String function)
```

where function object is actually the whole java script method. I need to call this method with nashorn

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
```

I need to pass the function with map item as well. When js function modifies the map object I have to print it out in java.

I would appriciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use invokeFunction method on Invocable [ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html#invokeFunction-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- ]

Nashorn engine implements javax.script.Invocable interface. From your "selectMethod" java method, you could do something like:

```
((Invocable)engine).invokeFunction(function, item);
```

I assume the script function name passed is that of a global script function [which was already defined in engine via "eval" call done earlier].